# Uploading all opened files in dreamweaver?

Tags: ide, dreamweaver, sftp

Is there a way to upload all the opened documents to the current site without having to load em manually?

At the moment for each opened document I select one and I press `Ctrl+shift+U` but it's kinda lame if you edited more than 10-20 files

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, upload all open is not built in. A long while ago I wrote a Dreamweaver extension called Get Put All, which allows for getting or putting of all open documents. It should still be available for sale (probably $5 or under) at the [CommunityMX](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=F03D5) web site (down for me at the moment). I no longer contribute to CommunityMX, so I won't see any proceeds. While written a while ago, it should work fine in newer versions of Dreamweaver.

Comment: cannot believe this is not built-in. doh apple. Anyway down for me too

Comment: I found an interesting post here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3558573#3558573 basically you can click "select all files recently modified" Problem is it doens't work here with CS5 :@ :@

Comment: Errata: I meant adobe not apple.

Comment: If by it doesn't work that you get an error, then try following one of the steps listed here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/405/kb405604.html

Comment: thanks i found a solution (i deleted some folders and then started to work)

Answer (score 5):

There is no native function however I have this simple cheat I use:

1. Open up the find and replace dialogue
2. Do a search for a string that appears in all the open documents. The page title usually has something useful.  Make sure "all open documents" is selected. Click "Find All"
3. The panel appears that shows you all the instances of your search (should be all the open files)
4. Highlight all the file names in the search results panel, right click, and click "put"

It actually only takes a few seconds and saves you the pain of having to put each file individually.  This is obviously for cases where simply highlighting the files and clicking the put button isn't feasible (e.g. files in multiple directories, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I was a big fan of the Get Put All Extension, but it does not work on `CS4 or CS5`.

Answer (score 1):

In CS6 (not sure about older versions), when viewing the local site, right-click on the project's parent directory, hover on 'Select' and then 'Checked Out Files.'

This will highlight all the files you have checked out and allow you to check them in with one click.

Note: As Dreamweaver gathers all of the check in status information from the server, this can take quite a while if it is a large project.  Only suggested for smaller projects, in which case it seems to work great!

Following the same process, you can also select 'Recently Modified', which only searches your local site and is much faster (but doesn't directly answer the check in/out part of your question).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just found out how to do it.

Use ctr+select all the files in the tree view under files and then right click on the selected entries and click "put"

Comment: this is normal..  I asked how to do this without having to select them manually.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

**1)** Click on "Site"

**2)** "Manage Sites" (Select the site you want to manage)

**3)** "Edit"

**4)** "Remote Info"

**5)** And tick the checkbox "Automatically upload files to server on save"

*(See where I am going here)*

Have all the files you want to upload OPEN on Dreamweaver

**6)** Then "Find" a common code each document has

**7)** And "Replace ALL" with the **EXACT** same code

***Make sure "Find in: OPEN DOCUMENTS" is selected before you do the replacement**

Once Dreamweaver has find and replaced the exact code - all documents will be unsaved at this point.

**8)** Just click "Save All" and voila!!! Now your CTRL+SHIFT+U fingers can chill the F out!

Hope this helps!

Oh, Remember to uncheck "Automatically upload files to server on save" afterwards or when not needed

PS: When you click "Save All" - you might get Dreamweaver saying "NOT RESPONDING". Just leave dreamweaver alone until it's done because it's uploading files at a rapid rate depending how fast your internet is :)